# What is the backstory behind the (1986) movie Labyrinth?

Tags: labyrinth

In the movie Labyrinth (1986) the character Sarah in a way becomes a part of her play, the one she is seen rehearsing in the beginning of the movie. We know that the goblin king, Jareth is in love with her, but because we never see or hear of any part of the story before she wishes her baby brother Toby away. We don't know of any pre-existing relationship between the two even just through her playbook.

**Is there any story before the events of the Labyrinth movie, especially between the characters Jareth and Sarah that would explain their relationship in the movie?**

Answer (score 3):

Jarleth doesn't seem to be in love with Sarah. Mostly he just seems to want the baby. Note that he tries to palm her off with a bauble, then threatens her a bunch of times to **go away**.

> She willed her eyes to close. From behind shut eyelids, she heard a voice answering. It was her own voice, but it seemed to be a memory. “I — I can’t. It isn’t that I don’t appreciate what you’re trying to do for me … but I want my baby brother back. He must be so scared …” She opened her eyes again.
>   Jareth snorted, and tossed his mane of blond hair. He had lost patience with the girl. With a wave of his hand, he extinguished the crystal. With another wave, he plucked a live snake from the air. He held it with a straight arm in front of him, so that it writhed and hissed near Sarah’s face. Then he threw it at her. “Don’t defy me,” he warned her.
>
> <sub><sup>[Labyinth: Official Novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Jim-Hensons-Labyrinth-Novelization-Henson/1608864162)</sup></sub>

and

> “You are no match for me, Sarah.” Jareth sounded impatient. “Let the child alone. Take my gift. I will not offer it to you again.”
>   Before he could produce the crystal, Sarah told him, “No.” She paused. “Thank you all the same, but I can’t do what you want. Can’t you see that? I must have my brother back.”
>   “You will never find him.”
>   “Ah,” Sarah said, and took a deep breath. “Then … there is a place to look.”
>   Just for a moment, Jareth’s face flinched. Sarah saw it, the merest trace of fear fleeting across his eyes. Was it possible? His nostrils tightened, he gripped his cane, and appeared to hesitate slightly before answering her. She could not quite believe it, but the suspicion that the Goblin King could be afraid of her, even if only momentarily, was encouraging.
>   “Yes,” he said. “There is a place.”
>   And now, with a really hammy gesture straight out of vaudeville, he twirled his hand and pointed through the window.
>
> <sub><sup>[Labyinth: Official Novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Jim-Hensons-Labyrinth-Novelization-Henson/1608864162)</sup></sub>

Later he poisons her and tries to rape her, then throws her into a pile of garbage. When she finally arrives at his castle, he offers to make her his queen but only as a distraction to stop her from saying the words that will destroy him.

> You have no power over me

Comment: Just because you use roofies doesn't mean your trying to rape someone